# what is the purpose of {documentname} in the RouteTemplate config?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore

> By default, Swagger JSON will be exposed at the following route -
> "/swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json". If necessary, you can change
> this when enabling the Swagger middleware. Custom routes MUST include
> the {documentName} parameter.

Why does the template config require this placeholder but the UI config does not?

```
app.UseSwagger(c =>
{
    c.RouteTemplate = "api-docs/{documentName}/swagger.json";
})
NOTE: If you're using the SwaggerUI middleware, you'll also need to update its configuration to reflect the new endpoints:

app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/api-docs/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
})
```

What is `{documentName}` for? Is there a feature to swap it out dynamically or something? Because the UI config in the example has it statically configured. why wouldn't it just be `"/api-docs/v1/swagger.json"` in the RouteTemplate config too?

Comment: Were you able to understand the need for {documentName} ?

Comment: Did you figure this out?  The documentation completely brushes over this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### documentName

The `{documentName}` refers to the name you specify in the `AddSwaggerGen()` method.

The following code uses `myapi` as the name for a swagger document.

```cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
  options.SwaggerDoc("myapi", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" })
);
```

Using `UseSwagger` as follows

```cs
app.UseSwagger(options =>
  options.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json");
```

leads to a swagger file being created the following location:
`/swagger/myapi/swagger.json`

Which means your Swagger UI configuration must be

```cs
app.UseSwaggerUI(options => {
  options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/myapi/swagger.json", "Swagger v1");
});
```

The Swagger UI can make a UI based on any swagger file, whether it comes from this project or not. That's why it doesn't include the `{documentName}` placeholder. There isn't a relationship between these, necessarily.

### Multiple Swagger UIs

This, for example, is the configuration where I have 1 Swagger Doc, 2 swagger files, and two UI endpoints. I describe the same API, but once using the OpenAPI v3 standard, and once using the old Swagger v2 standard.

```cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
  options.SwaggerDoc("myapi", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
});

app.UseSwagger(options =>
{
  options.SerializeAsV2 = true;
  options.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/swaggerV2.json";
});

app.UseSwagger(options =>
{
  options.SerializeAsV2 = false;
  options.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/openapiV3.json";
});

app.UseSwaggerUI(options => {
  options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/myapi/openapiV3.json", "OpenApi v3");
  options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/myapi/swaggerV2.json", "Swagger v2");
});
```

When you go to the swagger UI, you will see a dropdown to select one of the two endpoints.

### Multiple Swagger Docs

Your app can also have multiple swagger docs. E.g. your 'normal' API + some legacy API stuff.

```cs
options.SwaggerDoc("myapi", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
  options.SwaggerDoc("myapiLegacy", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My Legacy API", Version = "v1" });
```

There are several ways to specify when a method of your project belongs to a certain swagger doc. But the easiest way is to mark it with an attribute:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "myapiLegacy")]
public void Post([Product product)
```

So since you can have multiple swagger docs, it makes sense to create a placeholder for it. i.e., `{documentName}`.

In my swagger UI I now end up with 4 endpoints:

- normal api as Swagger V2
- normal api as OpenApi V3
- legacy api as Swagger V2
- legacy api as OpenApi V3

Comment: A lot to digest, it is not at all obvious this is how it all works (at least for me). Is there really no official documentation that has this level of explanation? Quite frustrating to have to seek this out on SO instead of just having readable documentation!